# SQLAlchemy autoflush doesn't work in FastAPI

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI with SQLAlchemy. I have a middleware that adds a database session to request.state as described in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#alternative-db-session-with-middleware. I tried creating the session with autoflush=True but found that it has race condition issues where sometimes the flush would happen as I expected and other times it would happen too late. This can cause a record to not be inserted into the database when I assumed it would be.

What is causing autoflush to fail to work?

Comment: Does it makes difference when you override like this? `request.state.db = SessionLocal(session_options={"autoflush": True})`

Comment: Did my suggestion made sense? @hekevintran

Comment: Hi @YagizcanDegirmenci I tried this and it caused an error "AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'db'".  I can't find any argument called `session_options` in SQLAlchemy docs either.  My question is really about why the FastAPI docs recommend autoflush=False.  The code samples have this, but the doc doesn't explain why.  Do you have an idea on that?